# Axios.all for dynamic post calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

I am new to node js,I have to make dynamicpost call to my server for that I am using axios.all this seems to be easy at first.I don't how to get the response for dynamic changing post queries Still don't get it see the example

```
function getThatAxiosMultiple(PhotoDataBlob,postId) {
    let ReturnThatAxios = [];
    PhotoDataBlob.map(data => {
        let pushThis = axios.post('/postthispic',{data,postId})
        ReturnThatAxios.push(pushThis)
    })

    return ReturnThatAxios
}

function getResponseLength(PhotoDataBlob) {
    let returnThis = []

    for(let i=0;i < PhotoDataBlob.length;i++){
        let response = `response${i}`;
        returnThis.push(response)
    }
    return returnThis.join() // response1,response2,response3....
}

let postId = 'XXXXX';
let getReadyresponseLength = getResponseLength(PhotoDataBlob);     //this dynamic changing variable is not accesible
console.log(getReadyresponseLength)
let axiosMultipleArray = getThatAxiosMultiple(PhotoDataBlob,postId)
axios.all(axiosMultipleArray).then(axios.spread((  getReadyresponseLength )//response1,response2... => { 
    console.log(getReadyresponseLength)
}))
```

Any other way how to do it ?